# ContentResolver.insert always returning null

Tags: android

I am trying to set a custom ringtone by pressing a button but getting null from ContentResolver's insert method. Following is the code resopnsible for setting the ringtone. I checked on stackoverflow itself and some users said its working for them but in my case I get the variable "newUri" as null

The sound file gets created at the desired location so I know that "newSoundFile" is ok.
Upon printing "values" variable in log gives the following.

Values are title=my ringtone is_notification=true mime_type=audio/mp3 is_alarm=true is_ringtone=true _size=8733 is_music=false artist=None _data=/mnt/sdcard/media/ringtone/myringtone.mp3

```
try
{
     uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
     Log.d("Test", uri.toString());
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "my ringtone");
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "None");
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
     Log.d("Test","Values are "+values.toString());
     newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
     Log.d("Test", "Exception is " + ee);
}
if(newUri == null)
    Log.d("Test", "newUri is Null");
 else
    Log.d("Test", "newUri is "+newUri.toString());
```

Comment: where is `mCr` initialized? and post the stacktrace

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this code.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "my ringtone");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "None");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile
        .getAbsolutePath());
getContentResolver().delete(
        uri,
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\""
                + newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
        RingtonesPlaying.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
        newUri);
```

Comment: This solution will work, but not the recommended way to do it. You should query for existence of the uri, and insert only if not present instead of invoking a delete-insert pair each time

Comment: Is anybody else getting the following exception using this code on Android Pie?
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table files has no column named title_resource_uri (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO files(_data,title_key,parent,_display_name,format,title_resource_uri,is_music,title,is_ringtone,artist_id,bucket_id,_size,is_alarm,date_added,date_modified,mime_type,media_type,is_notification,album_id,bucket_display_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

Answer (score 3):

Don't set the duplicate file name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).