# Android get default ringtone file path

Tags: android, ringtone

This code gives me the default ringtone:

```
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(App.get(), Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
```

How can I get its absolute file path, something like

```
/data/data/com.myapp/sound.ogg
```

`ringtone.getTitle(context)` returns `Default ringtone (Song Name)`

and

`ringtone.toString()` returns

```
android.media.Ringtone@418f7b30
```

Comment: Refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419867/contentresolver-insert-always-returning-null/22419908#22419908

Comment: String defaultPath = Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI.getPath();