# getContentResolver().insert returns null Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am new to building cordova plugins and I am trying to build a plugin that sets the default mobile ringtone, currently I have this code

```
ContentResolver resolver = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + ringtoneName);

Log.wtf("RINGTONE", "path: " + file);
if (file.exists()) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, ringtoneTitle);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    Log.wtf("RINGTONE", "values : " + values);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Log.wtf("RINGTONE", "uri : " + uri);

    Uri newUri = resolver.insert(uri, values);
    Log.wtf("RINGTONE", "new uri : " + newUri);
    if(newUri != null){

            try {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
             RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);

            Log.wtf("RINGTONE", "done");

             } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.wtf("RINGTONE", "error: " + e);
             }
    }
} else {
    Log.wtf("RINGTONE", "ringtone not found");
}
```

The problem is that `newUri` always returns `null`
I have tried to set

`resolver = this.cordova.getActivity().getBaseContext().getContentResolver();`
and
`resolver = this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver();`

but with the same result.
I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22419908/12943158) that suggests to delete the current uri before setting a new one, by adding this line before the insert:
`resolver.delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);`

and it actually worked, but it doesn't completely solve the problem, because I can't seem to set notification or alarm ringtone at the same time, because the previous line removes everything, also the same problem happens when trying to set custom ringtone for contacts.

Comment: Have you tries Uri newUri  = Uri.fromFile(file); ?

Comment: Even if you had got a valid uri your code would not work as you did not copy your file to that new uri. Further you cannot use the .DATA column on Android 10+ devices.

Comment: Do you mean as the value for data column? or where to use that line exactly? I'm not sure how file uri would help me here, the uri im using in insert() is content uri where I should insert the row which is something like ```content://media/external/audio/media```

Comment: I read about data column deprecation in Android 10+
what do you suggest to do for Android 10+ devices?

Comment: Well did you try Uri.fromFile()? Who said you need to use a content scheme uri to install a ring tone? If so then you could use a FileProvider too.

Comment: ohh I understand, you mean to set ringtone directly from file uri, I have tried before, and I just retested it, unfortunetly it did not work. I test on android 5, it may work on other phones

Comment: I noticed this line in the logs  
**W/SettingsInterface( 1596): putStringForUser()  Setting name isringtone value is :file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/music.mp3 userHandle is :0**